# I entered the data this way to draw multiple plots, but it gives an error. What do I need to change or add in the code?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The problem seems to start with plt.plot(x,y) but I don't know how to fix it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
x = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [5, 12, 19, 21, 31, 27, 35]
z = [3, 5, 11, 20, 15, 29, 31]
plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.plot(x, z)

plt.show()
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 y = [5, 12, 19, 21, 31, 27, 35]
      4 z = [3, 5, 11, 20, 15, 29, 31]
----> 5 plt.plot(x, y) 
      6 plt.plot(x, z)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2757, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2755 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   2756 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2757     return gca().plot(
   2758         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   2759         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:1632, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1390 """
   1391 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1392 
   (...)
   1629 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1630 """
   1631 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1632 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1633 for line in lines:
   1634     self.add_line(line)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:312, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    310     this += args[0],
    311     args = args[1:]
--> 312 yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:498, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    495     self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
    497 if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 498     raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    499                      f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    500 if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    501     raise ValueError(f"x and y can be no greater than 2D, but have "
    502                      f"shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (5,) and (7,)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have a `ValueError` referring to the shape of the input.

You must provide lists/arrays of same shape within a `plot` call. Here `x` is shorter than `y`/`z`.

You can either provide more points in `x` or trim `y`/`z`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
x = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [5, 12, 19, 21, 31, 27, 35]
z = [3, 5, 11, 20, 15, 29, 31]
plt.plot(x, y[:len(x)]) 
plt.plot(x, z[:len(x)])
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

plt.plot(x, y) is trying to plot the y values vs the x values, but since you have fewer x values than y values, a ValueError occurs.  If you are trying to plot y and z vs x you need len(x) = len(y) = len(z).  Your code would look like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, (ax1, ax2)  =plt.subplots(1,2)
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [5, 12, 19, 21, 31, 27, 35]
z = [3, 5, 11, 20, 15, 29, 31]

ax1.set_title('x y')
ax1.plot(x, y) 

ax2.set_title('x z')
ax2.plot(x, z)

plt.show()
```

If instead you want all these plotted on one chart you can do this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [5, 12, 19, 21, 31, 27, 35]
z = [3, 5, 11, 20, 15, 29, 31]

plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(z)

plt.show()
```